# Check wheter $_POST is set with a self-defined function?

Tags: php, function, post, isset

I'm working on a function to check wheter a $_POST is set or not.

The following works fine:

```
if (isset($_POST['einfo'])) {
    $einfo = $_POST['einfo'];
} else {  $einfo = NULL; }
```

echo $einfo;

And this is the function i'm trying to make:

```
  function  ifset($check) {
       if (isset($_POST['$check'])) {
     $check = $_POST['$check'];
    } else {  $check = NULL; }
      return $check;
}

$einfo = ifset('einfo');

echo $einfo;
```

But i get no output.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: I can't imagine how this should be necessary. And if, don't call the function ifset, because that's not at all descriptive of what the function actually does.

Comment: Tnx a lot this helped me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use double quotes:

```
function ifset($check)
{
  if (isset($_POST["$check"]))
  {
    $check = $_POST["$check"];
  }
  else
  {
    $check = NULL;
  }
  return $check;
}
```

But actually you can omit them.

Comment: +1 (too). While AurelioDeRosa is right about showing the wrong output, your answer proves that the function itself is wrong as well.

Comment: Don't use double quotes at all. This is just a variable.

Comment: Tnx a lot for the fast reply this helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

If the result is NULL, when you do the echo it will be "casted" as empty string and so you see nothing.

Try to use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

And you have not to use the double quote to let php interpret the vars.

Comment: As will 'false'. If you need to output debug values like this, use `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL means empty so you see nothing. If you want to see something, try this:

```
function ifset($check) {
 if (isset($_POST["$check"])) { 
 $check = $_POST["$check"]; 
 } else { 
 $check = "Empty";
 } 
return $check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to read a php manual!

```
$_POST['$check'] -> string '$check' is as you write
$_POST["$check"] -> string "$check" is a string that contain the $check variable
$_POST[$check] -> equivalent to previous


$check = 'some test';
echo "$check"; // outputs -some test-
echo $check; // outputs -some test-
echo '$check'; // outputs $check
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is obviously correct, but the comment "you need to read a php manual" is not needed. That could be the answer to almost any question and also sometimes you don't know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with even less code:

```
function ifset($check) {
    if (isset($_POST[$check])) {
        return $_POST[$check];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And depending on what values you deal with and are using PHP 5.3+ you can use:

```
function ifset($check) {
    return $_POST[$check] ?: NULL; // ternary operator
}
```